# Can't get ICU4J working with Saxon HE 10.3

Tags: java, xslt, internationalization, saxon, apache-fop

I'm trying to get the internationalisation plugin ICU4J working with Saxon HE 10.3.

I've got ICU4J on the Classpath, but Saxon HE 10.3 is not using it.

When formatting a date in a Stylesheet, for example with...

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-dateTime(current-dateTime(), '[h1]:[m01] [P] on [MNn] [D].', 'de', 'AD', 'DE')"/>
```

...ICU4J is not invoked to format the date.
How can I register/install ICU4J in Saxon HE 10.3?

Comment: I don't think ICU4J is just a plugin you put on the classpath and then any Java program magically has better internationalization support. So whether it is BaseX or Saxon HE, just putting ICU4J on the class path doesn't improve the date formatting capabilities, rather in the case of BaseX there is improvement in terms of the Unicode collation, as the BaseX code is set up to use ICU for that if available, but not for date formatting, for instance. My understanding for Saxon is that the commercial editions PE and EE come with ICU support, but due to code in the commercial com.saxonica classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ICU4J integration requires Saxon-PE or -EE.

See https://saxonica.com/products/feature-matrix-10.xml